# buildozer android debug deploy run error: Command failed: ['tar', 'xzf', 'apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz']

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy, buildozer

I'm getting the above error when trying to package up my kivy app.
After running `buildozer android debug deploy run` I am met the the below error:

```
Command failed: ['tar', 'xzf', 'apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz']
```

When running the above command (`tar xzf apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz`) I get the following output:

```
/usr/bin/gzip: 1: ELF: not found
/usr/bin/gzip: 3: : not found
/usr/bin/gzip: 4: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

[image]

Tried to look on line for anything close to this but haven't found anything relevant. Has anyone else seen this error?

Ubuntu Version Info:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

thanks

Comment: I tipped in the error with Ubuntu and got several answers that I believe would work for you… here is one that explains it well: https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/check-ubuntu-version

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I'm not trying to get my Ubuntu version. I'm trying to solve the error in the post title...

Comment: Just the "command failed" is not enough to go on. There can be many reasons. We need the actual error it produced

Comment: My apologies, I thought that Output was the issue. Have you attempted the command yourself? Each item in the array should be separated by a space… `tar xzf apache-ant-1.9.4-bin.tar.gz` if you cannot find that file on your system, you could make one to test the command.

Comment: Added the error now. Apologies I thought that command failed was sufficient

Answer (score 0):

I was missing p4a and its dependencies:

https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/

running:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential ccache git zlib1g-dev python3 python3-dev libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386 openjdk-8-jdk unzip ant ccache autoconf libtool libssl-dev
```

solved my problem